# Replacing the domain part of email address in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a users table that has email addresses.

In development, we don't want emails going out to these users, and at the same time we want to use this data.

I want to replace all the domain parts of the email address like:

```
john.smith@microsoft.com
```

with

```
john.smith@local.com
```

I want to run an update statment on the table to do this.

I have used REPLACE before, but I'm guessing will need a regex?

Comment: Why not just turn off email functionality in development?  In general a development environment for a system which sends emails would do well to have a fake SMTP listener for development/debugging purposes anyway.  The development environment simply shouldn't be pointing to a production email server.

Comment: Sql server doesn't support regex, but you can do what you need with PATINDEX() and SUBSTRING().

Comment: The data is going to be useless if you replace the domain information.  You could just invalidate the address completely by proceeding each with an @.

Comment: @David I'm testing emails, and I will replace it with something else where the emails will go out but to the QA server that can 'catch all' emails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CHARINDEX` to get index of `@`, `LEFT` to get part of email and concatenate `local.com`.

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(email NVARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #tab
VALUES ('john.smith@microsoft.com');

UPDATE #tab
SET email = CONCAT(LEFT(email, CHARINDEX('@', email)), 'local.com');

SELECT *
FROM #tab
```

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376791)**

If you use version lower than 2012 you need to concatenate with `+`:

```
UPDATE #tab
SET email = LEFT(email, CHARINDEX('@', email)) + 'local.com';
```

Comment: Note that CONCAT() became available starting with SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Regex Solution

```
CREATE TABLE tab(email text);

INSERT INTO tab
VALUES ('john.smith@microsoft.com');

UPDATE tab set email = regexp_replace(email, '(\S+)@\S+', '\1@local.com');
```